# Could someone explain what a 1-factorisation of a graph G means?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

**Definition**
A 1-factorisation of a graph G with 2n vertices is a partition of the edge-set into 1-factors

**Theorem**
$K_{2n}$ has a 1-factorisation

Could someone please explain to me what the definition means?
There is no explicit examples in my textbook and I am really slow when it comes to understanding topics in discrete mathematics...

Also, it is stated that all the platonic graphs have a 1-factorisation, but why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know what a $1$-factor is? Since that concept is used in the definition you quoted, it should have been defined earlier.  You should clarify whether your problem is with the notion of $1$-factor, with the notion of partition, or with something else, since that will affect the sort of answer you need.

Comment: @AndreaBlass: No, I do not know what a 1-factor is. But before the definition, it is mentioned that "the circle method yields a partition of the edge-set of $K_{2n}$ into $n$ edge disjoint perfect matchings (1-factors). The name 1-factor reminds us that each vertex in a perfect matching has degree 1 in that matching". The "circle method" was the method for making a fixture list of a fotball league containing $2n$ teams, where each team plays against all the others $2n-1$ teams during $2n-1$ days. Eg. 8 teams results in a fixture list of 7 days with 4 matches each day.

Comment: @HopefulStudent: Do you know what a [*perfect matching*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matching_%28graph_theory%29) in a graph is? That’s another name for a $1$-factor.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: Aha! Now I understand, thank you so much :D

Comment: @HopefulStudent: You’re very welcome.